# Kendo 2023.1.314-Individual Scripts not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo 2023.1.314 to include Charts in my application.
Kendo provides an option to use the complete set of library using kendo.all.js or just use the individual scripts.

When using the Kendo.all.js ,the chart control loads as expected.

However ,when trying to include the individual scripts as defined in https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/scripts/scripts-dataviz & running the application gives me the below error.

[image]
The Jquery version that i have is 3.6.4.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is not complete. If you try the [Kendo UI Custom Download](https://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download) tool and select only Charts from the DataViz the tool lists some other scripts that are missing in the table linked:

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.userevents.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.color.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.html.base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.html.icon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.drawing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.dataviz.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.dataviz.themes.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.dataviz.chart.min.js"></script>
```